# Unable to concatenate id with the URL link in the anchor tag

Tags: php, html, yii2

I want to concatenate the `id` with the URL link in the anchor tag. Currently, it only routes to the URL but is not getting the `id`, so `id` is not concatenating with the URL.

```
[
    'label' => 'online ordering link',
    'format' => 'raw',
    'value'=>'<a href="http://localhost:4200/clientSideDashboard/"'.$model->id.'">Generate Link</a>',
],
```

Comment: for the value you can use anonymous function: value=> function(){ return <a href="Url::toRoute(['product/view', 'id' => 42])">txt</a>;}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[
                'label' => 'online ordering link',
                'format' => 'raw',
                'value'=>'<a href="http://localhost:4200/clientSideDashboard/"'.$model->id.'">Generate Link</a>',
],
```

Would never work. When your concatenating value like that what you're generating is

> <a
> href="http://localhost:4200/clientSideDashboard/"[model-id]">Generate
> Link

Try :

```
[
                'label' => 'online ordering link',
                'format' => 'raw',
                'value'=>'<a href="http://localhost:4200/clientSideDashboard/'.$model->id.'">Generate Link</a>',
],
```